What kind of principles of reasoning can we use for classes in ZFC?
$\newcommand{\set}[2]{\{\ #1 \mid #2 \ \}}$
Motivation & Context
In ZFC, everything in the domain of discourse is a set and we can only talk about classes in the metatheory. But we still want to talk about classes since they simplify statements, for example, replacement can be stated as "the image of sets under class functions are sets" and comprehension can be stated as "the intersection of sets and classes are sets".
Formally, a class is a formula that binds exactly one variable, written as $\{\ x \mid \Phi \ \}$. In ZFC the only terms are variables (since we have no function symbols nor constants), but we want to treating classes as terms, so we define a way of elaborating (atomic) formulas that contain classes into ones that do not contain classes:

$x \in \set{x}{\Phi} \rightarrow \Phi[x/y]$
$x = \set{x}{\Phi} \rightarrow \exists a. a \in x \Leftrightarrow a \in \set{x}{\Phi}$
$\set{y}{\Phi} \in x \ \rightarrow \exists a. a \in x \land a = \set{y}{\Phi}$
$\set{x}{\Phi} = \set{y}{\Psi} \rightarrow \forall a. a \in \set{x}{\Phi} \Leftrightarrow z \in \set{y}{\Psi}$
$\set{x}{\Phi} \in \set{y}{\Psi} \rightarrow \exists a. a \in \set{y}{\Psi} \land a = \set{x}{\Phi}$

and a new substitution rule for classes:
$\set{x}{\Phi}[t/y] = \set{x}{\Phi[t/y]}$ if $y \neq x$, and $\set{x}{\Phi}[t/x] = \set{x}{\Phi}$
This is already enough if all we want is to use classes as abbreviations but not to reason about them, i.e., to use them in proofs. (Assuming the rewriting system we defined has various nice properties such as confluence and normalization, which I assume we can prove)
Some authors take this stance, for example Kunen wrote in his set theory

There is nothing wrong with thinking
about such collections, and they sometimes provide useful motivation; but
since they are outside the domain of discourse described by the axioms,
they must never appear in a formal proof.
-- p23

But I found this approach to be ultimately unsatisfying, for

We use classes informally all the time. Indeed, since formally we can only mention sets by variables, strings like $A \cap B$ and $\set{x \in \mathbb{R}}{x > m}$ are (abbreviations of) classes. (This can be somewhat worked around by using extension by definition).
In set theory we inevitably will want to use and reason about classes and class functions, for example in transfinite recursion theorem.

My question is: If we are to use (proper) classes in proofs, what kind of principles of reasoning can we use for them? Here's my attempt at answering this question:
I will use natural deduction as the proof system, since it closely resembles everyday mathematical reasoning.
Inference Rules
So, what inference rules can we use for formulas containing (proper) classes? It seems to me that all the propositional rules are still valid (need verification?). $=_I$/Reflexivity seems also to be valid. But the quantifier rules and the $=_E$/Substitution might not apply since

Proper classes are not sets, even though we use them in place of terms.
We've modified how substitution is defined.

An example of (1) is the following 2 proofs:
$\mathbb{V} = \mathbb{V} \rightarrow \exists x. x = \mathbb{V}$ by $\exists_I$
$\forall x. \exists y. y = x \rightarrow \exists y. y = \mathbb{V}$ by $\forall_E$
Which are both obviously invalid. To me this indicates that both $\exists_I$ and $\forall_E$ need some modification. But I'm not sure what modifications are satisfying (i.e. sound and complete), does requiring $\exists x. x = t$ as an additional premise suffice?
I can't really think of an example of (2) so I cannot judge its impact on the inference rules.
Extension by Definition
Extension by definition can solve a lot of the problems I described, for example we could extend our language with a 2-ary function symbol $\mathrm{ap}$ for function application so that $f(x) := \mathrm{ap}(f, x)$ is in fact a term for all variables $f$ and $x$. Similarly, we can define new function symbols for big union (at the cost of admitting $\bigcup \varnothing = \varnothing$), 2-ary union, intersection etc.
It seems to me (I'm not entirely sure) this solves almost all the problems if you are only using non-proper classes. Of course, you still cannot talk about proper classes.
There is a catch to this solution though: all the defined functions need to be total, i.e., they must be defined for every set (or pairs of sets). So $\bigcap$ cannot be introduced as a new function symbol since $\bigcap \varnothing = \mathbb{V}$ which is not a set, which means it's not defined for $\varnothing$.
Quantifying over Classes
There's also the issue of quantifying over classes, i.e. when we have variables that represent some non-specific classes. It seems that to talk about them formally means we need to expand our language again.

Downvoters pls explain how I could improve my question

It seems like a good question to me. Typically if you have an argument using classes, you have to think through what it “really” means. But it would be useful to have a formal exposition of what’s allowed in such arguments (maybe someone has done this, but if so, I’ve never seen it).

Your question seems to conflate definitional extensions and proper classes. Both of them involve introducing new predicates with their definitions, but they should be distinguished. You may also check second-order set theories to see how to handle proper classes.

I know that extension by definition cannot turn proper classes into actual terms. Also, I'm specifically interested in (first-order) ZFC.

After reading a bit about MK it seems that it’s strictly superior than ZFC in terms of ergonomics, it’s a shame that there’s hardly any books written on class-set theories.

What's the question exactly?

@MikhailKatz How should we modify rules of inferences if we want to use classes in place of terms
